# Trouble with converting phonegap plugin to work with plugman

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, steroids, plugman

I'm working on an iPhone app via AppGyver Steroids and it requires that phonegap plugins be installed via [plugman](http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/creating-your-project/using-plugins/using-custom-plugins/making-plugman-compatible/how-to-make-plugman-compatible). I found a plugin that I desperately need but it isn't compatible with plugman. I've been trying to convert it, but I'm stuck. The javascript layer is working fine, but I can't seem to get it to talk to the native layer. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far:
https://github.com/stevethorson/phonegap-backgroundjs

I've edited the plugin.xml file and restructured the files, but I'm not sure if it's right.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. This branch already did what I was looking for.
https://github.com/colibri-software/phonegap-backgroundjs/tree/phonegap3